# Cron Job run between a range of minutes?

Tags: cron

Ok so I see all these questions about crons running every 10 minutes, every whatever minutes, but it's SET. However, I want mine to RANDOMLY run every 10-15 minutes. Between those ranges so sometimes it'll pick 13 min, 12 min, etc.

Is there any possible way you can do that on a shared server? Or would I have to program it via PHP and have that script run everytime someone visits the page I want to refresh?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: You could wrap the script you are trying to run in say a shell script and have that shell script run every minute.
Then have the shell script take care of the random time

Comment: Hmmm that seems pretty good, but isn't that really useless to make the script run every minute? Or does that not require a lot of... resources to do that?

Comment: As long as the code that determines the randomization is short it shouldn't matter too much.

I do agree that it seems like there should be a better solution, but you might try that until somebody else posts something better.

Answer (score 0):

I usually let the cronjob run every 10min and in the script itself that cron executed I place at the header of the script a sleep+random number of the extra random "window" I need - i.e: in your case 5min => 300sec

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?
sleep( rand(1, 300) );

print "starting job ! \n"
?>
```

Comment: If we use this to hit php file then server going down, Any idea about that?